# JAX-RS: Double @PathParam passing

Tags: rest, jax-rs, path-parameter

I would like to pass Double path params like 5, 5.0, 0.5, 3.5, 3.65 etc.

So I make such method on JAX-RS resource:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/rated-above/{minAvgRating : \\d+(\\.\\d+)? }")
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
 public Response getProvidersOnAverageRatedAbove( @PathParam("minAvgRating") Double minAvgRating,
                                                         @BeanParam PaginationBeanParam params) throws ForbiddenException {
             // method 
 }
```

But this method seems to doesn't work correctly even without Regex pattern.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: pl.salonea.jaxrs.utils.ErrorResponseWrapper of media type: application/octet-stream
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
```

## UPDATE

Sorry without regex it works correctly there is some problem with regex 
 **\d+(\.\d+)?** I have been also trying to use:  **[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?** and just **\S+** (not white space)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `BigDecimal` instead of a `Double`, e.g.

```
@GET
@Path("/rated-above/{minAvgRating}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getProvidersOnAverageRatedAbove(@PathParam("minAvgRating") BigDecimal minAvgRating, @BeanParam PaginationBeanParam params) throws ForbiddenException {
  Double myDouble = Double.valueOf(minAvgRating.toString());
  // .. and then use myDouble
```

Comment: It's odd but I thinks there is some problem with IntelliJ compilation deployment as this hasn't been working about 20 min and then whan I have rewritten it without pattern and than again with the above pattern it starts to work